# I have a checkbox that is a bit in sql 2008 server; when it's checked it will run a stored proc

Tags: php, sql

like so:

```
if (post('tranfer') == 1 && $patient->exists)
    {
    sql::query("exec event.dbo.sp_tran " . $patient->hex);  
    }
```

when it's unchecked it should run a reverse stored proc.

since it's a new check box in the table..none of the members will be checked automatically, they will all have 0.
so i'm afraid i can't use a simple else statement..

```
else (post('tranfer') == 0 && $patient->exists)
        {
        sql::query("exec event.dbo.sp_reverse " . $patient->hex);   
        }
```

would that work or am i missing something detrimental to this piece?

Comment: What's `post('tranfer')`? Do you mean `$_POST['tranfer']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($patient->exists) {
  if (post('tranfer') == 1) {
    sql::query("exec event.dbo.sp_tran " . $patient->hex);
  } else {
    sql::query("exec event.dbo.sp_reverse " . $patient->hex);
  }
}
```

UPDATE:

To detect when someone has changed the value of the checkbox, put a hidden field in the form that contains the old value of the column:

```
echo '<input name="old_tranfer" type="hidden" value="' . $patient->tranfer .'">';
```

Then when processing the form, you can do:

```
if (post('transfer') != post('old_transfer') && $patient->hex) {
  if (post('tranfer') == 1) {
    sql::query("exec event.dbo.sp_tran " . $patient->hex);
  } else {
    sql::query("exec event.dbo.sp_reverse " . $patient->hex);
  }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be nearly the same as what I wrote above?

Comment: It depends on what `post('tranfer')` returns if the field isn't in the post data at all. Browsers don't send anything for unchecked boxes.

Comment: well after i checked it and saved it... i <?php print_r ($_POST); ?>
and it returned an empty.. Array ( )

Comment: post('tranfer') is the exact same as $_POST['tranfer']

Comment: Does your form use `method='get'`? Does the checkbox have a `value` attribute?

Comment: That wouldn't change anything would it?

Comment: If it doesn't have a value, there's nothing to send in the form submission. And if it uses method='get' you should be using `$_GET['tranfer']`, not `$_POST['tranfer']`. You can also use `$_REQUEST['transfer']` to allow either.

Comment: so how would it know to run the reverse stored proc if it's 0 in the db?

Comment: That's why it's in the `else` clause -- if the box isn't checked, it won't be 1. I don't understand your question, what does the value in the DB have to do with it? Your question just says to base the action on the checkbox. Do you need to compare the checkbox with what's currently saved? That's different from what you wrote.

Comment: i would suppose but since it's a new checkbox everything in the field ['transfer'] is null atm. except for my test account.

Comment: What do you mean by "new checkbox"? Newer than what?

Comment: I just added it to an existing form and in the sql table.

Comment: So? The browser doesn't have any memory of the old form. It just sends everything that's in the form. If you check the box it sends the value, if you don't it doesn't.

Comment: OK, I think I understand your problem. You need a way to tell the difference between someone actively UNCHECKING the box on a patient that had it set already, and just LEAVING the box unchecked on a patient that didn't have this new field set in the first place.

Comment: exactly... that's exactly what i need.  =]  sorry for the confusion.